# how can I rotate an object around a point other than the origin point with glm::rotate?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to make my world rotate around my camera no matter where my camera is. I am not doing any crazy math yet, I am leaving middle school this year and I don't know what quaternions are. My problem is that every time I use glm::rotate function for anything it only allows me to rotate around an axis at the origin point and I can't find a way to fix this. if there is any somewhat simple answer to this problem I am having please let me know how I can rotate my world around any given point. thanks

```
glm::mat4 look(1.0f);
float Rrotation;
Rrotation = 20.0f;
glm::vec3 the_axis_not_orientation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

look = glm::rotate(look, Rrotation, the_axis_not_orientation);
```

Comment: One way is to do a translation so the centre of rotation becomes the origin, rotate around that origin, then translate all rotated points back.   The math isn't hard to derive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually do is to rotate the model:

```
model_view = look * rotate
```

If you want to rotate the view, then you have to swap the order of the matrices. Note, the matrix multiplication is not [Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property):

```
model_view = rotate * look
```

For your code that menas:

```cpp
glm::mat4 rotate = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), Rrotation, the_axis_not_orientation)
look = rotate * look;
```